# Can you have 2 "if" statements next to each other within the WordPress Loop? What is best practice?

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create the single.php post page for a WordPress blog. I have used the Loop to pull through the actual content but would also like to show the tags (if there are any)!

The first code snippet works perfectly and displays everything I want it to, but is it the best way to write it? **Can I use 2 if statements next to each other or is this bad practice?** I have tried both methods: 2 IF statements works but 1 IF statement doesn't...see below!

Thanks in advance!

**Working Code Snippet (using 2 IF statements)**

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="blog-content row">
    <div class="col">
    
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>

        <p class="single-date"><?php echo get_the_date();?></p>
        <?php the_content();?>
    
    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>

    <?php
      $tags = get_the_tags();
      if( $tags ) :
         foreach( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <div class="single-tag">
               <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id);?>">
                        <?php echo $tag->name;?></a>
            </div>
      
   
      <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      
  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Invalid Code Snippet (attempt to use only 1 IF statement)**

Here, I get the following warning: *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="blog-content row">
    <div class="col">
    
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>

        <p class="single-date"><?php echo get_the_date();?></p>
        <?php the_content();?>

    <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php $tags = get_the_tags();
          foreach( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <div class="single-tag">
               <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id);?>">
                        <?php echo $tag->name;?></a>
            </div>
   
          <?php endforeach; endif; ?> 
      
  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="comments-sec">

  <h4>Comments</h4>
  <?php comments_template();?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1.2:**

> Can I use 2 if statements next to each other or is this bad practice?

Yes you can, but in your case you can't... tags are passed after the post has been called upon. **You need to have a post to check if that post has tags.**

In your case, you're talking about two different loop, **one is for posts** and **one is for tags**, Both if statement are not related. You're running a loop for tags inside a loop for posts.

**Best practice is to have a fallback every time**

```
<?php 
//START Posts loop
if ( have_posts() ):
while ( have_posts() ):
the_post();
//IF posts exist
echo the_title().'<br/>'.the_content();

//START Tags loop
if( has_tag() ) {
//IF tags exist
echo the_tags();
} else {
//IF no tags exist, then fallbak
echo 'No tags yet!';
};
//END Tags loop

endwhile; else:
//IF no posts exist, then fallbak
echo 'No posts yet!';
endif; 
//END Posts loop
?>
```

Additionally you can use `has_tag()` and `the_tags()`.

More @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/ for `has_tag()`

More @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/ for `the_tags()`

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! I realised after posting that not all of my code snippets were showing, so have updated them now! Does your answer still apply?

Comment: Yes, loops are pretty generic most of the time, the same loop apply to the `index.php`, `single.php`, `page.php`, `category.php`... etc. Most of the time, the template is different but not the loop. You might not have to display tags or content on the front page, but you might want to do it on the `single.php`. `If` & `else` statement are pretty much based on what you're trying to achieve, designed wised.

Comment: If this answer your question don't forget to check the mark on the left side, to close this question.